# Android IME Database Suggestion

Tags: android, database, performance, search, ime

I am trying to build an Android IME similar to [Swiftkey](http://swiftkey.com/en/).

I want to look up in a database to provide suggestions/replacements for words and this needs to be real time and real quick. What database should I use that can provide the fastest search time? Haven't done something like this before and am new to Android. Anyone who has worked on something like this before? Any suggestions on what I can use?

Answer (score 2):

You might have some special requirements on the type of database but if not the android SQlite is really good and fast. Have look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Comment: Hey thank you! :) 

How about the query processing time? Have you worked on something similar before?

Comment: Hi @ArjavJain, Welcome to stackoverflow. I have used SQLite and find it good for many use cases. Have you looked at the SQLite documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try Realm for fast processing https://realm.io/